# JSX wrap div in <a> tag if url exists

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to wrap  tags around an element (an svg icon) if a url is added. I have:

```
<Fragment>

  { url && (
    <a href={ url }>
  ) }

      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ myIcon } />

  { url && (
    </a>
  ) }

</Fragment>
```

I keep getting `Syntax error: Unexpected token (170:7)` for `</a>`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What am I doing wrong?" you are thinking of jsx as html string. It is not. JSX is javascript syntax extension to simplify `React.createElement` calls.

You could extract the inner part to a variable and use ternary operator to conditionally wrap it

```
const icon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ myIcon } />

return (url ? <a href={url}>{icon}</a> : icon)
```

Comment: Should const `icon` not be an arrow function where I pass `myIcon`? Or it just works like that if adding the const to render()?

Comment: It should be an element making it a component is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

JSX parse your `</a>` tag as invalid syntax, so you need to use another way:

```
<Fragment>

  { url? (
    <a href={ url }>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ myIcon } />
    </a>
  ) : (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ myIcon } />
  )}

</Fragment>
```

Comment: I'm trying not to repeat `<FontAwesomeIcon>`. It does not look good

Comment: You can't avoid this